# Unmarshal HTML nested in XML

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I am receiving an xml file from a 3rd party which has an HTML element within one of the XML tags. I cannot work out how to unmarshal this to get the href URL.

XML Example:

```
<SOME_HTML>
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  google</a>
</SOME_HTML>
```

This is as far as I have got so far but not adding anything to the struct:

```
type Href struct {
    Link string `xml:"href"`
}
type Link struct {
    URL []Href `xml:"a"`
}
type XmlFile struct {
    HTMLTag []Link `xml:"SOME_HTML"`
}

myFile := []byte(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOME_HTML>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    google</a>
</SOME_HTML>`)

var output XmlFile
err := xml.Unmarshal(myFile, &output)
fmt.Println(output) // {[]}
```

Comment: "but not working" meaning what? What problem are you having?

Comment: It is printing {[]}

Comment: Welcome @asnow!. `<SOME_HTML>...</SOME_HTML>` which I'm guessing you've chosen to keep your example simple doesn't really tell us the kind of HTML you're expecting. HTML (as opposed to XHTML) has tag omission and other shortform syntax which, when inserted as a string into XML will make go's XML parser (or any other for that matter) fail hard. But it could well be that you're receiving HTML in XML serialization; it's not 100% clear from your question. So please show us actual HTML you're receiving.

Comment: The example is pretty much exactly what I am receiving, only difference is some other fields around it and the tag is actually <DISPLAY_NAME_HTML>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like that (https://play.golang.org/p/MJzAVLBFfms):

```
type aElement struct {
    Href string `xml:"href,attr"`
}

type content struct {
    A aElement `xml:"a"`
}

func main() {
    test := `<SOME_HTML><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a></SOME_HTML>`

    var result content
    if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(test), &result); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Parsing everything in the xml, assuming also there could be more than one `a` tag in the html or other tags (like a `div`).

If this is not needed, just replace `XmlFile.Links` with `XmlFile.Link` of type `Link` (not `[]Link`)

```golang
func main() {
    type Link struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"a"`
        URL     string   `xml:"href,attr"`
        Target  string   `xml:"target,attr"`
        Content string   `xml:",chardata"`
    }
    type Div struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"div"`
        Classes string   `xml:"class,attr"`
        Content string   `xml:",chardata"`
    }
    type XmlFile struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"SOME_HTML"`
        Links   []Link   `xml:"a"`
        Divs    []Div    `xml:"div"`
    }

    myFile := []byte(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOME_HTML>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">facebook</a>
    <div class="someclass">text</div>
</SOME_HTML>`)

    var output XmlFile
    err := xml.Unmarshal(myFile, &output)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(output)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jZDVr6dk5Ro)

Edit: Added more tags in the xml to show how to parse different tag types.

Answer (score -1):

You can parse the example you posted using a regular XML parser, there are however a whole lot of exceptions to the XML syntax which are commonly accepted as valid HTML.

The simplest example I can think of is : all html interpreters I know of understand that `<br>` (an unclosed `<br>` tag) is the same as a self closing `<br />` tag.

If you don't know how the HTML on the other end of the service is generated, you are better off using an HTML parser.

For example, there is the [`golang.go/x/net/html`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/html) package which provides several functions to parse HTML :

https://play.golang.org/p/3hUogiwdRPO

```
func findFirstHref(n *html.Node, indent string) string {
    if n.Type == html.ElementNode {
        fmt.Println("  * scanning:" + indent + n.Data)
    }

    if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "a" {
        for _, a := range n.Attr {
            if a.Key == "href" {
                return a.Val
            }
        }
    }
    for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
        href := findFirstHref(c, indent+"  ")
        if href != "" {
            return href
        }
    }
    return ""
}

func main() {
    doc1, err := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(sample1))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("href in sample1:", findFirstHref(doc1, ""))
    }
    
    doc2, err := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(sample2))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("href in sample2:", findFirstHref(doc2, ""))
    }
}

const (
    sample1 = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOME_HTML>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    google</a>
</SOME_HTML>`

    // sample2 is an invalid XML document (it has unclosed "<br>" tags):
    sample2 = `
    <p> line1 <br> line2
<a href="foobar" target="_blank">
  Some <br> text
</a>
</p>
`
)
```